# Extjs Grid ApplyState not reflecting the changes | Hide issue

Tags: extjs, extjs4

When we have multiple parent-child grid and want to re config the grid after load call like this:

```
listeners: {
     'afterrender': function (grid) {      
      var state =grid.getState();
      state.columns[1].hidden= true;
      grid.applyState(state); 
    }
}
```

This behaviour is even still reproducable on ExtJS 6.5.1.

For Example
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?306941-Apply-state-after-grid-reconfigure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's still an issue with applyState. When grid is having multiple hidden columns and we use applyState function it crash our grid. So we have skip the hidden property part although it's working smooth for width change , filters etc.

```
listeners: {
     'afterrender': function (grid) {      
      var state =grid.getState();
      state.columns[1].hidden= false;
      grid.applyState(state); 
      grid.columns[3].hidden = true;
    }
}
```

if you manually set hidden property of column it'll hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an override I've been using to fix the hidden columns issue. I am using 6.6 so not sure if this will work in 4.4, though. Also, you may not need to suspend/resume layouts but not sure on that either.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.overrides.Grid', {
            override: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

            applyState: function () {
                this.callParent(arguments);

                Ext.suspendLayouts();
                Ext.each(this.getColumns(), function (column) {
                    if (column.hidden) {
                        column.show();
                        column.hide();
                    }
                });
                Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue under ExtJS 6.2.2.

I nailed it down where the hidden and width/flex state of the column isn't applied correctly if it has already been rendered:

`Ext.grid.Panel.applyState()` -> `Ext.panel.Table.applyState()` -> `Ext.grid.header.Container.applyColumnsState() / Ext.grid.locking.HeaderContainer.applyColumnsState()` -> `Ext.grid.column.Column.applyColumnState()`

The following override will fix this (see the lines with "added" comment):

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.column.Column, {
    applyColumnState: function(state, storeState) {
        var me = this,
            sorter = me.getSorter(),
            stateSorters = storeState && storeState.sorters,
            len, i, savedSorter, mySorterId;
        // If we have been configured with a sorter, then there SHOULD be a sorter config
        // in the storeState with a corresponding ID from which we must restore our sorter's state.
        // (The only state we can restore is direction).
        // Then we replace the state entry with the real sorter. We MUST do this because the sorter
        // is likely to have a custom sortFn.
        if (sorter && stateSorters && (len = stateSorters.length)) {
            mySorterId = sorter.getId();
            for (i = 0; !savedSorter && i < len; i++) {
                if (stateSorters[i].id === mySorterId) {
                    sorter.setDirection(stateSorters[i].direction);
                    stateSorters[i] = sorter;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // apply any columns
        me.applyColumnsState(state.columns);
        // Only state properties which were saved should be restored.
        // (Only user-changed properties were saved by getState)
        if (me.rendered) { // added
            var originalBeforeShow = me.beforeShow; // added
            if (state.hidden == null) { // added
                me.beforeShow = function() { // added
                    delete me.hidden; // added
                    originalBeforeShow.call(me); // added
                }; // added
            } // added
            me[!(state.hidden == null ? me.getInitialConfig().hidden : state.hidden) ? 'show' : 'hide'](); // added
            if (state.hidden == null) { // added
                me.beforeShow = originalBeforeShow; // added
            } // added
        } else { // added
        if (state.hidden != null) {
            me.hidden = state.hidden;
        }
        } // added
        if (state.locked != null) {
            me.locked = state.locked;
        }
        if (state.sortable != null) {
            me.sortable = state.sortable;
        }
        if (state.width != null) {
            if (me.rendered) { // added
                me.setFlex(null); // added
                me.setWidth(state.width); // added
            } else { // added
            me.flex = null;
            me.width = state.width;
            } // added
        } else if (state.flex != null) {
            if (me.rendered) { // added
                me.setWidth(null); // added
                me.setFlex(state.flex); // added
            } else { // added
            me.width = null;
            me.flex = state.flex;
            } // added
        }
    }
});
```